# Can one only get the last message and not the entire history?

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft Graph one can get an email message. That message is often a reply to an earlier message with, for instance, a summary of the sender and the subject as well as the earlier message included. Is it possible to only get the last message and not the earlier ones?

Comment: You mean, can we convince people to stop top-posting? I wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the uniqueBody of the email message by using the $select parameter. This will get the content of only the last message in that conversation thread.