# how to remove original message in replies and forwards using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

we need to fetch all mails based on the conversationId, mails are replying with the same email they received. they will not delete original message when they replied. so the replied mail has the original message.
the problem is when we fetching the mail using graph api, it will return the whole message (including the original message).
is there any way to get mail response without the original message?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the history email content ? For example, A reply an email to B, you do not want to show the original email sent from B to A when you request the graph api ?

Comment: @HuryShen exactly. i want to remove the previous original message from the api result

Comment: Found this answer in another post. "UniqueBody" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445098/can-one-only-get-the-last-message-and-not-the-entire-history

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can't be implemented by graph api because the history email is a part of the new email's body. So we can just show all of the email's body in the graph api.

For a workaround, we can do it in code development. When we get the response data from the graph api, we can parse the json and get the `body.content`. Then we can substring the content string and just keep the content in front of the "**From:**". But if we do the substring operation on the `body.content`, it may cause some problem because it contains lots of html tags. So I suggest you to do the substring operation on the field `bodyPreview`, just substring the `bodyPreview` and keep the content in front of the "**From:**".

By the way, if you can let the users delete the history email body before sending the email, that's best(Although I know it may not be possible~).

Comment: first of all we can not do the substring operation on bodyPreview or body.content. because each mails are different format and different style. so it's not working

Comment: @syamlal Is it possible to parse the `body.content` html, and remove the original email. No matter what method is used, it should be a bit troublesome I think.

Comment: i almost done this. i used a html parser for parsing mail content to html content. in some cases, we got the original  old mail inside the blockquote tag, so we can remove the data inside the tag. then we can avoid original old mail. unfortunately most of the mails are not containing any seperation or not including in any blockquote. its very difficult to identify where is the old orginal content started